# How to convert list object to Pandas Dataframe with defined format?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

How to convert list object to Pandas Dataframe with defined format?

Printed list has this output (Jupyter):

```
(u'variable',    price  threshold
0   13.5      100.0
1   10.0        NaN)
(u'standard',    price  threshold
0   12.5      300.0
1   11.0        NaN)
(u'fixed',    price  threshold
0   14.5      250.0
1   10.1      200.0
2    9.0        NaN)
(u'standing-charge',    price
0      9)
```

Converted to Pandas Dataframe:

```
    0               1
0   variable        price threshold 0 13.5 100.0 1 10...
1   standard        price threshold 0 12.5 300.0 1 11...
2   fixed           price threshold 0 14.5 250.0 1 10...
3   standing-charge price 0 9
```

I need:

```
type       price  threshold
variable    13.5   100
variable    10.0   NaN
...
```

Please, help ;)

Comment: What are the elements in those lists? DataFrames?

Comment: Oh, and the index of you DataFrame has to be unique, so your `I need` is not possible.

Comment: It's output from parsing json file:

rows_list = []
for index, row in ds.iterrows():
        a = {}
        a = row['plan'], json_normalize(row['rates']) 
        rows_list.append(a)
print rows_list

Comment: type(rows_list) is list

Comment: How to parse this format? Haven't seen any similar format yet.

Comment: And what is `type(row_list[0][1])` ?

Comment: Maybe, you should show the complete code.

Comment: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: Aha, so you have a list of tuples with `(unicode, DataFrame)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you clearified what is in you list, you could do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, df2 in row_list:
    df2['index'] = key
    df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```